# Can use Desktop SSD drives for servers front panel bays on SFF

Tags: hardware

Can I use Desktop SSD drives (example : [WD SSD Blue 1TB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LXPENRR)) into a SFF server bay (Example [HP DL360](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QCVVF7D))

**Exactly :** instead of buying a Enterprise SFF SSD drive , buy 16 x of Desktop grade SSD and install it into front server bay.

**Questions** :

1. Can I do this ?
2. What I need to do it ? (is SFF 2.5" caddy is in market ? that can install SSD drives into it and insert into server ?)

*Note: I don't find any resource on internet about this or anyone do this before or asking ;)*

Comment: it is possible but unusual

Comment: 1) usually works but a) is not supported by HP and b) sometimes causes issues ie bad temperature readings - try with a sample before buying all SSDs! 2) Yes, spare part number for the liked Server is 651687–001.